# How to install imagick on MAMP?

Tags: php, macos, mamp, imagick, pecl

When I run `sudo pecl install imagick`, I receive the following error:

```
checking ImageMagick MagickWand API configuration program... checking Testing /usr/local/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
checking Testing /usr/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
checking Testing /usr/sbin/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
checking Testing /opt/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
checking Testing /opt/local/bin/MagickWand-config... Doesn't exist
configure: error: not found. Please provide a path to MagickWand-config or Wand-config program.
ERROR: `/private/tmp/pear/install/imagick/configure --with-php-config=/usr/bin/php-config --with-imagick' failed
```

Not sure what this error is implying. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

you need to install imagemagick first:

using homebrew:

```
brew install imagemagick
```

**or** using macports:

```
sudo port install imagemagick
```

then you can install the php package as :

```
sudo pecl install imagick
```

Answer (score 1):

You need libmagickwand-dev to install extension using pecl.